# Show current section in navbar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my application (Angular2 RC6) I have a navbar with all the sections of the application.
When I click on a section (or if I specify the section in the url) I need to highlight that section.

To achieve this intent I'm using something like that:

```
router.events.subscribe (e => 
{
    if (!(e instanceof NavigationEnd))
        return;

    this.sectionChanged.emit (e.url);
})
```

The problem with this approach is that `e.url` is a string and it is boring to compare that string with all the paths: e.g.

```
if (path == "/main/users")
    highlightUsersSection();
if (path == "/main/blabla")
    highlightBlaBlaSection();
```

Furthermore I should do it 2 times because I hightlight the section and also I write the section name in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html) directive for that. It adds a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.

Here's an example:

```
template: `
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
`,
```

Comment: Is it just a name, or a link?

Comment: Just a name. Maybe in the future I will convert it in a link

Comment: If it's a link, you can just use the same technique, the routerLinkActive directive will work for any <a> tag. No idea how to do that for a simple name though..